# How to convert boolean to string at query binding?

Tags: php

In repository, I built a query and I want to bind value, but I need to convert the $isAllowed boolean value to a string ('true', 'false' or 'null'). How to do it in the right way?

```
':isAllowed' => $isAllowed,
```

Comment: You can use if-statements before you bind the value. `if ($isAllowed === true) { $isAllowed = 'true'; }` and so on. However, I would rather recommend to set the database column as a tiny int and store it as `1` for true, `0` for false and let it be nullable. Storing booleans as strings are usually frowned upon since you then always need to do a string comparison in your code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson maybe you know a short form or some php func?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the advice, but why it would be better to use 1,0?

Comment: Because you can then just cast the value as a boolean in your code when you get it since `1` is a truthy value and `0` is a falsy value in PHP. You can even use it as a boolean without even casting it: `if ($valFromDb)` instead of `if ($valFromDb === 'true')`. The database lookup will also be faster (since comparing int's are faster than comparing strings).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
':isAllowed' => json_encode($isAllowed),
```

Example

```
json_encode(true); //  = 'true'
json_encode(false); // = 'false'
json_encode(null); // = 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a new variable or use an existing one like this:

```
$isAllowed_str = $isAllowedBool ? 'true' : 'false';
```

For NULL value, it should be considered false:

> When converting to bool, the following values are considered false:
>
> the boolean false itself
> the integer 0 (zero)
> the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
> the empty string, and the string "0"
> an array with zero elements
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> SimpleXML objects created from attributeless empty elements, i.e. elements which have neither children nor attributes.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

If you need to separate null value you could check with an if statement before casting bool to str:

```
if(is_null(isAllowedBool)) {
   $isAllowed_str = "NULL";
}
else {
   $isAllowed_str = $isAllowedBool ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

Comment: but 'null' is missed.

Comment: Thank you @GetUnstuck, I edited my answer, I missed the null part

Answer (score 0):

You can just do :

`':isAllowed' => $isAllowed ? 'true' : 'false'`

Check ternary operator here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: but 'null' is missed.